# Send additional data to KendoUI DataSource and use it in dataBound event

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I want to get some additional data in the dataSource to use it in the dataBound event.
Here is transport I use in the grid:

```
            "transport" : {
            "read" : {
                "url" : "f?p=120:0:701647109622339:PLUGIN=BC",
                "dataType" : "json",
            },
        },
        "pageSize" : 20,
        "schema" : {
            data : "row",
            total : "total",
            rowsdata : "rowsdata",
            model : {
                "id" : "doc_id",
            }
        },
```

I want to access `rowsdata` via `$('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().rowsdata`. Is it possible?

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M8jvz/10/

In this particular case, I want to pass a list of permanently hidden columns into HideGrouped function

Here is the fiddle with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/Casufi/4ya83/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()
```

Returns **array**. And what is that rowsdata inside your schema? Such configuration is not supported.

How to send addtional arguments to the server is covered [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read.data).

Comment: it looks like I put the wrong words.
I want to receive some additional data from server in the same request that use dataSource.
Is there any way to put an additional data to dataSource to use it in dataBound function

Comment: Don't know if it is correct.
I found needed data in g.dataSource._pristine.rowsdata[0]

http://jsfiddle.net/M8jvz/11/

Answer (score 1):

You can use dataSource.schema.data as an function to achieve what you want:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            "autoSync" : true,
            "data" : l_json,
            "pageSize" : 20,
            "schema" : {
                data : function(data){
                    data.rowsdata[0] = { hidden: 0, name: "name" }
                    return data.row;
                },
...
```

Documentation here:
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data

Comment: I found the solution. Please check my comment for Petur Subev